# Some contents hides in landscape mode android development

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new in app development I am working with constrained layout, I have added one image at the top, then some buttons [layout of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8PSD.png)
After the rotation image view got disappeared [Here is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv19p.png)
I have tried guide lines but not able to solve problem.
I have also added xml file so that you can understand the problem in more clear way.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signup"
        android:layout_width="297dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@color/fiv"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signin2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signin2"
        android:layout_width="297dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@color/fiv"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/skip"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="116dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/bmas"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.726" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Welcome to Daily Task Scheduler"
        android:textColor="@color/fiv"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signup"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/skip"
        android:layout_width="241dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Skip and continue"
        android:textColor="@color/fiv"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: have you created two different layout resource files?

Comment: Please post your xml, since we cant assume what the problem is.

Comment: Kindly have a look now, I have added the xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see your contents get hide, you can add **scroll view** this can solve your problem.
It is always best programming practice to add scroll view in each activity,hope it will help you.